# Using php mktime()

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql, webserver

I am having problem with `mktime()`. Here is my code where I am recording user logged time and date, if he is logged in for the first time then `$FirstTimeLogin` will be true else `$FirstTimeLogin` will be false.

Now the problem is if I login for the first time, I am getting a message:

> Today start1346716800 fail1

but I am actually looking for a message:

> Today start1346716800 success

I am getting this message if I login for the second time. I thought something is going wrong with `mktime()` also tried with `gmmktime()` again the same problem.

```
$chklogin = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT Attempt_Time FROM admin_loginattempts WHERE User_Email='{$User_Email}' AND Successful='Y' ORDER BY Attempt_Time DESC LIMIT 1"));

if (!$chklogin) {

    $FirstTimeLogin = true;
} else {
    $lastAttempt = strtotime($chklogin["Attempt_Time"]);
    $todaystart  = gmmktime(0, 0, 0, $Cur_Month, $Cur_Day, $Cur_Year);

    echo 'Last Attempt' . $lastAttempt . '<br>';
    echo 'Today start' . $todaystart . '<br>';

    if ($lastAttempt > $todaystart) {
        $FirstTimeLogin = false;
        echo 'success';
    } else {
        $FirstTimeLogin = true;
        echo 'fail';
    }
}
```

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/).

Comment: We don't have enough information. What's in `$chklogin["Attempt_Time"]`? How are `$Cur_Month`, `$Cur_Day`, `$Cur_Year` initialized?

Comment: What are the values for `$Cur_Month`, `$Cur_Day`, and `$Cur_Year`? It doesn't look like you ever set them.

Comment: Also what is the result of `echo 'Last Attempt'.$lastAttempt.'<br>';`?

Comment: Rather than `gmmktime`, why not just do `strtotime('today')`?

Comment: thanks for your reply guys... $chklogin["Attempt_Time"] will display the last logedd in time..iam initilising $CurTime=time();
$Cur_Date=date('Y-m-d');
list($Cur_Year, $Cur_Month, $Cur_Day)=explode("-",$Cur_Date);                                   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''result is                                                                                     LastAttempt1346787758                                                                    Today start1346716800

Comment: What do you mean _in time_? Can you show us a sample value?

Answer (score 0):

```
$lastAttempt = strtotime($chklogin["Attempt_Time"]);
$todaystart  = strtotime('today');
```

Actually your echos are just wrong

```
if ($lastAttempt > $todaystart) {
    $FirstTimeLogin = false;
    echo 'fail';
} else {
    $FirstTimeLogin = true;
    echo 'success';
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but i got the same result... Last Attempt1346789046
Today start1346803200
fail1 ........but if i refresh my page again then it works fine displaying  Last Attempt1346875463
Today start1346803200
success..again if i change the date to next day..i get same message at first login ....Last Attempt1346789046
Today start1346803200
fail1

Comment: but you have changed only echo statements how does it make difference ??actually speaking iam using that echo statements just to display and make sure to which loop is it going to....in my programme i dont use that echo at all..

Comment: As mentioned just your echo's are wrong the timestamps are showing as being correct

Comment: I would suggest the problem might be in your use of $FirstTimeLogin